# MAMP: make index.html default

Tags: apache, mamp

I am using MAMP to host a website.

I have index.html and index.php both inside a folder.

How can I make web server open index.html instead of index.php

THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you configure the right order of [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

Comment: I tried it. Worked. But it has screwed my drupal site. Now I have to clean drupal. THanks for the response though.

Comment: This worked for me. I wanted to add a comment for other people in the future.  
  
file -> edit template -> apache httpd.conf  

look for the DirectoryIndex property and add index.htm to the beginning of it.